# Responsive navbar using Python (Django), HTML, CSS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) guideline to create a responsive navbar that, according to the dimension of the screen, will show its elements in a dropdown list (instead of an inline, used for bigger screens).

Below the relevant part of the HTML (replaced some useless parts with "..." to improve and speed-up readability)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
<link rel="javascript" href="{% static 'javascript/responsive.js' %}">
</head>

<body>
  {% block sidebar %}<!-- insert default navigation text for every page -->{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}<!-- default content text (typically empty) -->
  <!-- Main Logo -->
  <div class="main-image" id="myMainImage">
    <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/images/logo.png"/>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="http://www...</a></li>
    <a href="http://www.../">Storia di Gabriella</a></li>
    <a href="http://www...">Video Gallery</a></li>
    <a href="http://www...">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <a href="http://www.../">Dicono di Noi</a></li>
    <a href="http://www...">Come Contattarci</a></li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ricerca..">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="respScreen()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
```

in the `static` folder (`mysite/articles/static`) I have created a javascript folder with a `responsive.js` file inside it

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function respScreen() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

and, finally, I have filled up the `styles.css` (in `mysite/articles/static/css`), below the relevant part

```
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home").
Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon.
This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

I cannot understand why, despite following exactly the guide linked, when I zoom in the page the navbar does not compact itself (instead, its elements tends to overlap each other).

**EDIT1**: I tried to copy the code from the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) in Pycharm and run it in my local Django server and it does not work. It seems to be an issue of configuration. 
Below the static path from the `settings.py`
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

If I can provide you with more information, please ask.

**EDIT2**: Console log below (CTRL + SHIFT + J in Firefox):

```
unreachable code after return statement  aU73Q4U9JMQ.js:1028:375
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  hscv
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  hscv
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Connection  1588510866-lcs_client_bin.js:99:385
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Connection  1588510866-lcs_client_bin.js:99:385
```

**EDIT3**: If you want to see the full project to review the other Django files, it is stored in [this](https://github.com/marcogdepinto/DjangoWeb) Github repository.

Comment: Can you show, your console logs? from developer tool in the browser.

Comment: Added at the end of the question. If something more is needed, please ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved inserting a script tag in the html with the javascript function as follow

```
  <script>
  function respScreen() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
      }
  }
  </script>
```